# Change default environment in anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, environments

By default, anaconda is using my `root` environment. However, I'm always using another environment called `py34` that I activate manually. Is it possible to change the default environment from `root` to another one?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm working on Windows. On Unix systems adding a line to `.bashrc` is a solution of course.

Answer (score 4):

You could add the following line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
source activate py34
```

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with developing on Windows, but [this](https://superuser.com/q/144347) might help? Another possibility is to use an IDE such as [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), which I can really recommend for developing python. There, you can change your project settings to your `py34` environment.

Comment: Yes indeed - but unfortunately not on Windows.

Comment: Yes, the link helps - but I still think there should be a more elegant way to change the default environment...

Comment: @pomodorochris Do you use an IDE? If yes, you can set the python interpreter accordingly.

Comment: Maybe that's something you could look into? I can really recommend [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)! I'm pretty sure you can use it on windows, too.

Comment: You should be aware that cmd's ["AutoRun" command line](http://superuser.com/a/144348) (it's not just a script path) is executed every time cmd.exe runs, including every time the CRT's `system` function (i.e. `os.system`) is called. So if you run a script like this you should set a sentry environment variable to keep it from running multiple times.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for pointing this out. Maybe you could resolve this in a separate answer? As I said, windows is not really my specialty.

Comment: @Lisa, I've never used Anaconda. If it uses a shortcut to a batch file to set up the environment, pomodorochris can modify that batch file to activate the desired virtual environment. That would be preferable to modifying what *every instance* of cmd.exe does.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

Search for the Activate.bat file, Usually it is in

> "C:\Users\Your_UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts"

Open Activate.bat file in any Text Editor and Append

```
activate Your_Environment_Name
```

Save it and after that whenever you will open Anaconda Prompt Your_Environment will get Activated by default instead of base environment.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but I tried updating the activate.bat, and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link to create a new env - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60820687/11383333

Once your env is created, you can use the answer mentioned by Jayesh to update the activate.bat file -

Let's say the new env name is python39, then the original line in activate.bat looks like this - 
      @CALL "%~dp0..\condabin\conda.bat" activate %*

Update it to this - 
      @CALL "%~dp0..\condabin\conda.bat" activate python38

Save it and restart your anaconda prompt