# Upgrade to python 3.8 using conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Python 3.8.0 is out, but I haven't been able to find any post on how to update to python 3.8 using conda - maybe they will wait for the official release? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 160):

You can update your python version to 3.8 in conda using the command

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.8
```

as per https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python.  Though not all packages support 3.8 yet, running

```
conda update --all
```

may resolve some dependency failures.  You can also create a new environment called py38 using this command

```
conda create -n py38 python=3.8
```

**Edit** - note that the `conda install` option will potentially take a while to [solve the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753988/what-does-conda-do-when-solving-environment), and if you try to abort this midway through you will lose your Python installation (usually this means it will resort to non-conda pre-installed system Python installation).

Comment: `conda update conda; conda create -n py38 -c anaconda python=3.8`?

Comment: You can drop the channel specification, since Python 3.8 is now on the default channel. Thus `conda create -n py38 python=3.8` will create a minimal environment with Python 3.8.

Comment: If I'm **not** in an environment, does `conda install -c anaconda python=3.8` **update** the base installation?

Comment: Yes this should be the case.

Comment: I wonder why Anaconda for python 3.8 version is still not out?

Comment: I can confirm it updates the base as I just did it. Conda-forge does offer a newer update of 3.8 for awareness.

Comment: "note that the conda install option will potentially take a while to solve the environment". In my case the conda message said it would take 'several minutes', this ended up being about 5 hours...

Comment: Guys mine is over 12 hours and repeats with things like `17%Finding shortest conflict path for python-/ teutil[version='>=2.1,<2.7.0']:  1Finding shortest conflict path for python-dateutil[version='>=2.1,<2.7.0']:  18%|▏| 61/343 [12:10:13<8:24:26, 107.33s/it]` I'm newby to Python. Shall I leave it run?

Comment: @nba2020 that's absurdly long. It's probably NP-hard to calculate dependencies or something. At this point it'd be much faster to create a new conda env and install what you need.

Comment: The install command which specified you have specified - does it install python 3.8 along side existing python (I have 3.6 existing) or does it upgrade the existing to 3.8?

Comment: @nba2020: I can confirm, it takes forever to compute a long list of conflicts and it stops there. So, there does not seem to be a way to upgrade python from 3.7 to 3.8

Comment: I got numerous (a few pages) warnings about diverse packages conflicts and I still have Python 3.7.7.

Comment: what does `conda install -c anaconda python=3.8` do?

Answer (score 50):

**Open Anaconda Prompt (base):**

1. Update conda:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

2. Create new environment with Python 3.8:

```
conda create -n python38 python=3.8
```

3. Activate your new Python 3.8 environment:

```
conda activate python38
```

4. Start Python 3.8:

```
python
```

Comment: This solution got the job done and worked like a charm in Anaconda Prompt, but it didn't got available outside it. Any clue on how to make the activated python available system wide?

Comment: You will need to switch to your newly created python environment using command conda activate

Comment: It is only showing like 17 items on the list. why not the full list?

Comment: When I active using windows command shell it failed. Later, I change to directory where my environment installed, then typed just "activate" solved my issue. I validate by typing python gives me latest 3.8.2 version. I search for the environment directory by "conda info --envs" in the command line.

Comment: This solution is correct but what should be done to upgrading python in base env?

Answer (score 26):

Now that the new anaconda individual edition 2020 distribution is out, the procedure that follows is working:

Update conda in your base env:

```
conda update conda
```

Create a new environment for Python 3.8, specifying anaconda for the full distribution specification, not just the minimal environment:

```
conda create -n py38 python=3.8 anaconda
```

Activate the new environment:

```
conda activate py38

python --version
Python 3.8.1
```

Number of packages installed: 303

Or you can do:

```
conda create -n py38 anaconda=2020.02 python=3.8
```

--> UPDATE:
Finally, Anaconda3-2020.07 is out with core Python 3.8.3

You can download Anaconda with Python 3.8 from
https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

Comment: That link is dead

Answer (score 8):

## Update for 2020/07

Finally, Anaconda3-2020.07 is out and its core is Python 3.8!

You can now download Anaconda packed with Python 3.8 goodness at:

- https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual