# Can't upgrade Anaconda base to Python 3.8

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to upgrade my base environment to Python 3.8. According to the [official documentation](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python), I should just run `conda install -c anaconda python`. This, however, only upgrades Python 3.7, so, in the end:

```
(base) C:\Users\bob>conda install -c anaconda python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


(base) C:\Users\bob>python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

`conda update -c anaconda python` only updated a number of packages, but not Python itself.

And if I specify a version, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568175/upgrade-to-python-3-8-using-conda), after two hours analyzing dependencies, the upgrade fails because of conflicts.

I managed to set up a 3.8 environment, but I'd rather upgrade my base environment as it's the one my system path for use outside of Anaconda.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why use the base environment, instead of creating separate environments?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't appear to be possible to update the base version of anaconda to 3.8 yet because of the conflicts you mention. I assume once all the standard packages are updated to support 3.8+ (and updated versions of all dependencies), then the anaconda release will include 3.8.x as the default. This might take a while.

The problem here is version conflicts in the packages that anaconda installs by default. The reason you can install 3.8 in a clean environment is because no other packages are installed in that environment, so no conflicts.

This does now present a solution, although it requires reinstalling everything from scratch...

disclaimer: I don't use windows, so adapt my instructions accordingly to your OS.

- Remove your existing anaconda install from the path and delete
  anything in your bashrc (or windows equivalent) that points to it.

  - You can just delete/uninstall anaconda, but it's good to have a backup just incase, so leaving it there and removing links to it is a good option.
- Download and install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), and put it in your path as you had before.
- Install python 3.8 in the base environment `conda install python=3.8`
- Install all the packages that you need to do whatever you do.

Depending on what you install, at some point you may run into the same conflicts that prevent a standard anaconda install from updating at the moment, but that hasn't happened for me.

Comment: As of now miniconda supports up to python 3.7.

Comment: Yes, and you can upgrade a fresh install of miniconda to python 3.8 very easily by following that dot point of my instructions. Then you have a base environment at 3.8, which is what the OP is after.

Answer (score 2):

The latest *stable* version of anaconda is version 3.7

Please see here:

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

There isn't an option to get python 3.8, this is due to anaconda sometimes running a version behind the release of python.

Comment: Except there is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568175/upgrade-to-python-3-8-using-conda . One can create a conda environment with python 3.8, but updating the base environment is where the problem lies.

Comment: I agree it is possible to do that - but it doesn't mean it stable or fully supported yet.

Comment: Not according to the references I indicated in my post, including Anaconda's own documentation. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found there is a 2020-07 release of Anaconda with Python 3.8 https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual