# Upgrade Python and all packages in anaconda base env

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using anaconda and my current python version in it is **Python 3.7.10**.

I want to upgrade everything: anaconda, the **python version** (which includes a major version upgrade to 3.8, I read somewhere that that matters), and all anaconda packages within I want to upgrade too.

I want to do this in my **base anaconda env** i.e. just upgrade everything.

Of course I can do this by uninstalling and then downloading latest version and installing anaconda again. But I want to avoid complete reinstallation.

I was reading the answers here

[Upgrade to python 3.8 using conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568175/upgrade-to-python-3-8-using-conda)

but it's not clear to me... how does one do this update in his base env?

Side question: I see version 3.9.2 for Python available here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python but the current full download of anaconda includes just Python 3.8. Why is that difference?
How can I do so that I have the latest and greatest of all packages (incl. the python interpreter)? Should I go for Python 3.8 or 3.9? I guess if I install 3.9 some anaconda packages might not work, is that so?

Comment: Why do you not want to uninstall and reinstall or create a new environment ?

Comment: @ygorg Because I would have to do it every time a new major Python version comes out. I just want to avoid it. I know I can do it that way but I just want to avoid it.